# How to query the print queue on Windows

Tags: .net, windows

We are developing a critical application and need to have the finest control over the documents printed.  To be sure on which documents are printed or not we want to check the printer queue.

How can we query the print queue on Windows (status, queue list, errors, ...)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[EnumPrinters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162692(VS.85).aspx) to get the list of printers, [EnumJobs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162625(v=vs.85).aspx) to get a list of jobs for that printer. [GetJob](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144894(VS.85).aspx) to get info on a specific job and [SetJob](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162978(v=vs.85).aspx) to change the settings for that job (pause or cancel it).

See more in the [Printing and Print Spooler References](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162863(VS.85).aspx).

.NET has the [PrintQueue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.printing.printqueue(v=vs.110).aspx) and [PrintServer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.printing.printserver(v=vs.110).aspx) classes.

Answer (score 1):

Following URLs may be of interest to you,

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/printing/printwatchvbnet.aspx

and

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/printing/EMFSpoolViewer.aspx